# How to export database from Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ddl

Really would appreciate any help whatsoever on this one.

How to generate DDL from Application Express... including the actual data.

I can create a DDL; but one which contains none of the necessary inserts into the database tables. :<

There is no command console in Application Express.

Comment: Someone please correct me if I'm wrong here, but I believe DDL is not supposed to include insert statements. I suggest that you use the DDL file to create the database objects. Then use another method to export the actual data. There is an XML export/import utility in APEX 4.2 in **SQL Workshop > Utilities > Data Unload** that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another tool, such as SQL Developer, which can export the data as INSERT statements; alternatively, use Oracle's schema export utility (expdp) which can either export just the data or the entire schema if you like.

Comment: Yes; SQL Developer's export was exactly what I used - although thankfully I had already linked SQL Developer to the Application Express database.